# Objects initialized in BeforeAll function of hooks.js are not available in subsequent page js files

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

I am using Puppeteer framework for automating an application, where I intend to use BeforeAll function of hooks.js file to initialize certain parameters that I want to use in subsequent js files that have functions for corresponding steps of a feature file. Here is an example of BeforeAll function in hooks.js file.

```
BeforeAll({timeout: 100 * 1000}, async function () {
  if (scope.shadowExists)
       puppeteer.registerCustomQueryHandler('shadow', QueryHandler);

     scope.env = process.env.NODE_ENV;
     scope.config = config[process.env.NODE_ENV];
     scope.shadowExists = true;
     scope.driver = puppeteer;
     scope.host = scope.config.url;
     if (!scope.browser)
     scope.browser = await scope.driver.launch({ headless: false, defaultViewport: null, 
       devtools: true, slowMo: 250, args: ['--start-maximized'] });

     if (!scope.context.currentPage) {
         scope.context.currentPage = await scope.browser.newPage();
         scope.context.currentPage.setViewport({ width: 1920, height: 1080 });
     }
     await scope.context.currentPage.goto(scope.host);
});
```

And here is the page file where I'm trying to use objects of BeforeAll.

```
const { Given, When, Then } = require('cucumber');
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const expect = require('chai').expect;
const {
    isFieldExists,
    clickOnItem,
    fillInFormField,
    takenToPage,
    getTextContent
} = require('../support/actions');
const { QueryHandler } = require("query-selector-shadow-dom/plugins/puppeteer");
const { loginPage } = require('../support/selectors');
const scope = require('../support/scope');
const config = require('../../config')

Given('the user is on the log-in screen', { timeout: 2 * 10000 }, async () => {
let isOnLoginPage = await isFieldExists(loginPage.userTextBox);    
    expect(isOnLoginPage).to.be.true;
});
```

> let isOnLoginPage = await isFieldExists(loginPage.userTextBox);

When I run this feature file, it throws an error on this line where it simply says that cannot find value of "undefined".